# refactoring large if else satement in java

Tags: java, if-statement, refactoring

I'm trying to refactor some code so I don't have a large if / else if statement if possible.

Here is the code:

```
if (Character.getNumericValue(num) == 0 ) {
        return bar0;
    }
    else if (Character.getNumericValue(num) == 1 ) {
        return bar1;
    }
    else if (Character.getNumericValue(num) == 2 ) {
        return bar2;
    }
    else if (Character.getNumericValue(num) == 3 ) {
        return bar3;
    }
    else if (Character.getNumericValue(num) == 4 ) {
        return bar4;
    }
    else if (Character.getNumericValue(num) == 5 ) {
        return bar5;
    }
    else if (Character.getNumericValue(num) == 6 ) {
        return bar6;
    }
    else if (Character.getNumericValue(num) == 7 ) {
        return bar7;
    }
    else if (Character.getNumericValue(num) == 8 ) {
        return bar8;
    }
    else if (Character.getNumericValue(num) == 9 ) {
        return bar9;
    }
    else {
        return bar10;
    }
```

Basically it checks if char num is equal to an int 0-9, then returns the associated numbers bar (which is of type string). Is there any way to make this better?

I would like it to be something like

```
if (Character.getNumericaValue(num) == x {
   return barx;
}
else 
   return bar10;
```

if that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a array of values and do something like

```
if(Character.getNumericaValue(num) < 10) {
    return array[Character.getNumericaValue(num)];
} else {
    return bar10;
}
```

of course if you're sure the `num` will not be less than 0.

Comment: If the values of barN change during execution, he has to build this array every time he'd do the if-statement. In that case, a switch statement is more efficient.

Comment: @IraBaxter OP should refactor each `barN` to `bars[n]`, including updates. Maintaining a set of ten indexed variables is itself a smell.

Comment: In my case they wont change, so this works. But yes if I did need to change it, I could just add another string to the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can have an array of the bar, `bars` and the method would return the `bar` element based on the index you pass.

```
public bar getBar(num){
    return bars[Character.getNumericValue(num)];
}
```

Make sure to cover all the edge cases according to your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array that will hold your bar values:

```
Bar[] arr = {bar0,.....,bar9};
int numb = Character.getNumericValue(num);
if(numb < 0 || numb >= arr.length){
   return bar10;
}
else {
   return arr[numb];
}
```

Comment: A switch statement is like to be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

What are `bar0` to `bar10` exactly?

You could do it using an array, looking up the desired element:

```
String[] bars = { bar0, bar1, ... };  // etc.

int numericValue = Character.getNumericValue(num);
if (numericValue >= 0 && numericValue <= 9) {
    return bars[numericValue];
} else {
    return bar10;
}
```

Comment: `bar0` is the first bar where u drink a beer on Friday night... `barX` is the series that follows :)

Comment: This also worked, but the selected answer was more concise.

And bar0 - bar9 represented a POSTNET code to be printed out given a number 0-9. For example: `bar0 = "||:::";`, and bar10 was just a string returning an error incase the method was handed an invalid char.

Comment: What I meant was, "what *type* are `bar0` to `bar10`?", apparently they are `String`s.